# What do you call the raised platform at the entrance of a room?

Tags: single-word-requests

I always see some kind of raised platform in a bathroom. This is used to prevent water getting out of the room. I wonder what is it called.

Comment: could you include a picture, as i am not sure if you just mean a step

Comment: I've seen bathrooms with raised floors, but this is done for aesthetic reasons, I've never seen it done to prevent water egress unless it's part of the bath or shower area where those areas have a sunken floor. As @WendyG says, picture would help.

Comment: @GGx Raising is as much functional as having a sunken area. It's not just for esthetics.

Comment: @Kris What function? Can you enlighten me. I've only ever seen raised or sunken floors constructed to sink or raise a bath or shower or have an area of the flooring stand out. Certainly not to keep water from egressing the room.

Comment: @GGx Sometimes the floor may be raised to provide special plumbing or other services under it. At other times, it may be for other reasons.

Comment: @Kris ahh... yes... didn't think of concealing plumbing. Thanks!

Comment: If it's used for a water check, it's called a sill or a curb.

Comment: It's not really a raised platform in most cases, it's a sunken floor in the bathroom. The higher part of the floor is on the same level as the circulation space outside the bathroom. This being the case you have a split level bathroom with the entrance level being higher than the main level.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are describing a [**threshold**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/threshold).

> A strip of wood or stone forming the bottom of a doorway and crossed in entering a house or room.

Typically it is used when two different types of flooring meet (e.g. the tile in a bathroom meeting the carpet in a hallway) to cover either a gap or height difference. It *might* prevent water from escaping if there is only a small overflow, but that is not the primary purpose.

[image]

Comment: A picture paints a thousands words. Good answer

Comment: Agreed! Good answer... but I wouldn't describe it as a "raised platform" I'll be interested to see if the OP accepts your answer @Skooba.

Comment: The question may not be very accurate, but the threshold satisfies "raised" "at the entrance" and "to prevent water ...".

Answer (score 0):

> What do you call the raised platform at the entrance of a room?

[image: platform entry]

My sense: an elevated **platform**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/platform)

> 1. (Architecture) a raised floor or other horizontal surface